# Is there a publicly available dataset that I can use that links 9 digit zipcodes with counties and states?

Tags: zip-codes, data, county, zip4, fips

I have a dataset which has 9 digit zipcodes and I am trying to match these to the state and county FIPS codes. Is there a publicly available dataset that will allow me to do this?

Comment: This is a question that I think would be more suited to the [opendata.se] Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

From the US Census: [TIGER County Shapefile](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/COUNTY/)

From this file you could Spatially Join your 9-Digit ZIP code file to the county file, and get the resultant State and county FIPs codes.

If you are wanting to match your 9-Digit codes to ZIP codes, then use [TIGER ZCTA5 Shapefile](ftp://ftp2.census.gov/geo/tiger/TIGER2014/ZCTA5/) with the same workflow as above, but now your resultant join will containt ZIP codes for states/counties.

Comment: Thanks for the links, my understanding was that geoids were essentially FIPS codes, which are present in the second file too. Which column/var in the second file is the zip+4 code? I was a little unclear on that.

Thanks again for this!

Comment: Not sure if that ZCTA5 file contains +4 ZIPs. The unique county identifiers come after the first two digits of the FIPS code.

Comment: Right, I have the ZCTA5 to GEOID cross walk. the Zip+4 are what I wanted, which the file doesn't have according to the documentation in the parent directory :(

Comment: Gotcha, might want to reword your question. The ZCTA file allows you to link 9-digit ZIPs to counties and states.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you're talking about the FIPS state codes? You can obtain publicly available data from somewhere like Tiger Line that have the codes (most of these datasets do) and perform a spatial join of your zip codes.

Here is a source with one for the whole world, sub-divided:

http://www.gadm.org/home

Comment: Not just FIPS codes, I am basically looking for unique county identifiers for 9 digit zip codes!